# ¿Como agrego productos a un treeview en Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Mi idea es hacer un sistema en el cual el usuario inserte productos en una lista mediante un boton. Ya probe muchas maneras pero no se me ocurre como hacer la función. Paso a adjuntar el código.

```
Label(frame1, bg = "White", text = 'Concepto : ', font = ("Roboto", 10)).place(x = 10, y = 20)
concepto = Entry(frame1, bg = "light gray", state = 'disabled')
concepto.focus()
concepto.place(x = 80, y = 20, width = "150", height = "25")

Label(frame1, bg = "White", text = 'Importe : ', font = ("Roboto", 10)).place(x = 10, y = 50)
importe = Entry(frame1, bg = "light gray", state = 'disabled')
importe.place(x = 80, y = 50, width = "150", height = "25")

# Frame 1 : Boton 'Agregar'
btnAgregar = Button(frame1, text = "Guardar", bg = "light blue", state = 'normal', command = lambda:agregar_productos())
btnAgregar.config(font = ("Roboto", 11))
btnAgregar.config(bd = 2, relief = "groove", borderwidth = 3, cursor = "hand2")
btnAgregar.place(x = 45, y = 100, width = "100", height = "30")

tree = ttk.Treeview(ventana, columns = 2)
tree.column("#0", width = "150")
tree.column("#1", width = "140")
tree.place(x = 670, y = 210, width = "300", height = "200")

def agregar_productos():
    global tree, concepto, importe
    if len(concepto.get()) != 0 and len(importe.get()) != 0:
        tree.insert("", END, text = [concepto], values = [importe])
        mensaje['text'] = 'Concepto {} fue adherido exitosamente!!!'.format(concepto.get())
    else:
        mensaje['text'] = 'Concepto e Importe son requeridos!!!'
    agregar_productos()
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo, es que no puedes escribir en los Label, porque los tienes en 'disabled', entonces no sé cómo quieres introducir los datos, borra de tu código esto: `state = 'disabled'`.
Luego, en el método 'agregar_productos' lo llamas otra vez así mismo al final, por lo tanto te va a agregar el mismo valor en el treeview tantas veces como tu profundidad de recursión máxima te permita.

Y por último, respondiendo a tu pregunta, tal cual lo tienes: `text=[concepto], values=[importe]` lo que estas haciendo es insertar el objeto en sí, guardándote en el treeview algo parecido a esto: '.54978824L.54979784L'. Lo que tienes que hacer en cambio es esto otro: `text=[concepto.get()], values=[importe.get()]` para así poder obtener el texto que hay en el Entry.